# How change origin from object with collision area without change pivot area of collision?

Tags: objects, 3d-view, selection-tools, collision, 3d-cursor

Please look the pictures.[image]

[image]

Have a explanation on the pics
Please help me if possible.its for spawn correct ragdoll object to position of the box.
Thanks

Comment: Try changing your collision bounds to be convex hull or mesh and see if the collisions work then.

Comment: The box is a character type i change to convex hull work bad the character its crazy very bad.my problem is when  endObject replace with a intanced group of rigodbodies its a ragdoll then  imstanced cant move origin too :/ the box origin in center.the instanced in botton made conflict to physics and distort mesh